# Regular expression to find files with underscores and optional extension

Tags: python, regex, string

This is for work, so I've changed the extensions and files to protect the innocent.

I am parsing text from a description looking for a file name in the format word_here and it can have as many underscores as needed plus an optional extension. I was able to come up with this regular expression which works

**Test 1**

```
text = 'Some text here: * my_file_stuff.mat * other_file * third_file *'

FILE_REG_EX = r'([\w]+_+[\w]+\.*[py|mat]*)'
res = re.findall(FILE_REG_EX, text)

print(res)
```

**Output 1**

```
python test_regex.py

['my_file_stuff.mat', 'other_file', 'third_file']
```

The problem is it doesn't work for stuff like this

**Test 2**

```
text = '|my_file|another_file.mat|O_HERES_ONE|_O_HERES_ANOTHER| | | |'

FILE_REG_EX = r'([\w]+_+[\w]+\.*[py|mat]*)'
res = re.findall(FILE_REG_EX, text)

print(res)
```

**Output 2**

```
python test_regex.py
['my_file|a', 'nother_file.mat|', 'O_HERES_ONE|', '_O_HERES_ANOTHER|']
```

I modified my regex to include the vertical bar, here

**Test 3**

```
text = '|my_file|another_file.mat|O_HERES_ONE|_O_HERES_ANOTHER| | | |'

FILE_REG_EX = r'([\w]+_+[\w]+\.*[py|plot]*)\|'
res = re.findall(FILE_REG_EX, text)

print(res)
```

**Output 3**

```
 python test_regex.py
['my_file', 'another_file.mat', 'O_HERES_ONE', 'O_HERES_ANOTHER']
```

and that works for the second one but now not for the first one. Part of the issue is I will be searching a description for text to look up where a file is at, and I have no way of knowing what formatting it will use for files, only that they will be something in the form of MY_FILE_HERE01.py with or without the extension.

I've tried using the not symbol to exclude the vertical bars in front and back, but that seems to come up empty for both strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex for both kind of inputs:

```sh
[a-zA-Z\d]+_\w+(?:\.(?:py|mat))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U98rsN/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[a-zA-Z\d]+`: Match 1+ of letters or digits
- `_`: Match an underscore
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\.(?:py|mat))?`: Optionally match `.py` or `.mat`

Comment: Fantastic! This does the trick. Can you explain the question mark with colons? I know the question mark by itself in something like 'Here?' would make the e optional and match Her and Here. I guess the same works for groupings of parentheses. But, not quite sure I understand it's use with the colon at the beginning of the grouping.

Comment: `(?:` makes start of a non-capturing group. It is a group that doesn't capture.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

`\|?\s*([\w\d]+[\_\w\d]+(?:\.?[\w\d]+[\_\w\d]+)+)\s*\|?`

Comment: That's close, but not quite. That picks up the text from 'Some text here:' as well  giving this output
['Some', 'text', 'here', 'my_file_stuff.py', 'other_file', 'third_file']

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are trying to do now. If the file description will definitely have an underscore `_` then the above answer will work, I thought the file could be something like `myfile`. Cheers! =)